# IMAP folder receives email Twice

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to develop an email listener using Java mail api. I am receiving same email twice, the scenario not happening every time; randomly occurs.

The following code is used to make IMAP connection

```
try {
            isConnecting.set(true);
            createSession();
            LOGGER.warn("session created "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
            store = session.getStore("imap");
            if(store==null){
                LOGGER.warn("store is null return from here"+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                return;
            }
            store.connect(imapServerAddress, imapLoginId, imapPasswrd);
            LOGGER.warn("Connecting successful "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
            folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
            LOGGER.warn("Folder creating "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
            if (timer == null) {
                timer = new HashedWheelTimer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            if (idleManager == null) {
                idleManager = new IdleManager(session, es);
            }
            if (folder == null || !folder.exists()) {
                LOGGER.warn("invalid folder exit from here "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                System.out.println("Invalid folder");
                return;
            }
            synchronized (folder) {
                LOGGER.warn("Folder sync "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                folder.addConnectionListener(this);
                folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                folder.addMessageCountListener(this);

                System.out.println("message count listener added");
                LOGGER.warn("message count listner added "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                if (folder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                    IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) folder;
                    System.out.println("enter idle");
                    LOGGER.warn("Idle condition "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                    idleManager.watch(f);
                    setIsConnected(true);
                    LOGGER.warn("Folder.watch "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                    DbUtil.updateMediaStream(getIdentifier(), true);
                    isConnecting.set(false);
                    connectionAttempt.set(0);
                    LOGGER.warn("Db updated "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                    System.out.println("idle done");
                    scheduleTask();
                    LOGGER.warn("Scheduler starts "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
                }

            }

            System.out.println(new Date()
                    + "================================== connect() end");
            LOGGER.warn("____________________END connecting "+getIdentifier() +"on Imap"+imapLoginId+" pw "+imapPasswrd);
        } catch (Exception fex) {

                if (connectionAttempt.get() >= 3) {
                    LOGGER.error("Reconnection Failed", fex);
                    connectionAttempt.set(0);
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Error while connecting mediaStream", fex);
                }
                LOGGER.error("Reconnecting mediastream attempt "
                        + connectionAttempt.get(), fex);
                connectionAttempt.incrementAndGet();
                closeFolderAndStore();
                connect();

        }
```

The email is received here, the **"public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev)" method calling twice**

```
@Override
    public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
        Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
        System.out.println("Got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
        LOGGER.info("New message received {}" ,msgs.length);
        // Just dump out the new messages

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

            try {

                // msgs[i].writeTo(System.out);

                    System.out.println("-----");
                    System.out.println("Message >>" + msgs[i].getMessageNumber()
                            + ":");
                    LOGGER.info("Email Received >>> {}" , msgs[i].getMessageNumber());
                    processEmail(msgs[i]);


            } catch (Exception ioex) {
                LOGGER.error("messagesAdded:getmessagenumber", ioex);
                ioex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            synchronized (folder) {
                if (folder != null && idleManager != null) {
                    idleManager.watch(folder);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("messagesAdded:watch", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The IMAP debug log is follows

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QQBNADMAUABSADAANQBDAEEAMAAyADgALgBlAHUAcgBwAHIAZAAwADUALgBwAHIAbwBkAC4AbwB1AHQAbABvAG8AawAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=amith.bharathan@drd.co.in, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
A3 LIST "" inbox
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager select starting
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
* LIST (\Marked \HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX
A3 OK LIST completed.
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 463 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 36] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 7207] The next unique identifier value
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A5 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
* 1 RECENT
* 464 EXISTS
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager continue watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A5 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
A6 FETCH 464 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
* 464 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:31:06 +0000" "4444" (("Amith K Bharathan" NIL "amith.bharathan" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL (("Amith K Bharathan" NIL "amith.bharathan" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL NIL "<HE1PR06MB1196D2A9F2FDB040AB2B05B5BF230@HE1PR06MB1196.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>") INTERNALDATE "29-Jun-2016 14:01:07 +0530" RFC822.SIZE 19822)
A6 OK FETCH completed.
A7 FETCH 464 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 464 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "html" ("charset" "us-ascii") NIL NIL "7BIT" 1586 48 NIL NIL "en-US" NIL))
A7 OK FETCH completed.
A8 FETCH 464 (BODY[TEXT]<0.1586>)
* 464 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {1586}
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">555555555555<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A8 OK FETCH completed.
A9 FETCH 464 (BODY[TEXT]<0.1586>)
* 464 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {1586}
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">555555555555<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A9 OK FETCH completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A10 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
* 2 RECENT
* 465 EXISTS
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager continue watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A10 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
A11 FETCH 465 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
* 465 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:32:01 +0000" "test" (("Gopikrishnan V" NIL "gopikrishnan.v" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL (("Amith K Bharathan" NIL "amith.bharathan" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL NIL "<DB4PR06MB0464157DB21114B7E237B93C0230@DB4PR06MB046.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>") INTERNALDATE "29-Jun-2016 14:02:05 +0530" RFC822.SIZE 18300)
A11 OK FETCH completed.
A12 FETCH 465 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 465 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "html" ("charset" "iso-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 427 15 NIL NIL "en-GB" NIL))
A12 OK FETCH completed.
A13 FETCH 465 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 465 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A13 OK FETCH completed.
A14 FETCH 465 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 465 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A14 OK FETCH completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A15 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
* 3 RECENT
* 466 EXISTS
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager continue watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A15 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
A16 FETCH 466 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
* 466 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:35:56 +0000" NIL (("Gopikrishnan V" NIL "gopikrishnan.v" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL (("Amith K Bharathan" NIL "amith.bharathan" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL NIL "<DB4PR06MB0466336D31C8CE8919BD4B3C0230@DB4PR06MB046.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>") INTERNALDATE "29-Jun-2016 14:05:57 +0530" RFC822.SIZE 11747)
A16 OK FETCH completed.
A17 FETCH 466 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 466 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "html" ("charset" "iso-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 427 15 NIL NIL "en-GB" NIL))
A17 OK FETCH completed.
A18 FETCH 466 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 466 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A18 OK FETCH completed.
A19 FETCH 466 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 466 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A19 OK FETCH completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A20 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
* 466 EXPUNGE
* 466 EXISTS
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: request IdleManager to abort
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager continue watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager aborting IDLE for folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DONE
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A20 OK IDLE completed.
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait done, idleState 0: Thread[pool-21-thread-2,5,main]
A21 FETCH 466 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager done watching folder imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
* 466 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:35:56 +0000" NIL (("Gopikrishnan V" NIL "gopikrishnan.v" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL (("Amith K Bharathan" NIL "amith.bharathan" "drd.co.in")) NIL NIL NIL "<DB4PR06MB0466336D31C8CE8919BD4B3C0230@DB4PR06MB046.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>") INTERNALDATE "29-Jun-2016 14:05:57 +0530" RFC822.SIZE 13152)
A21 OK FETCH completed.
A22 FETCH 466 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 466 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ("text" "html" ("charset" "iso-8859-1") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 427 15 NIL NIL "en-GB" NIL))
A22 OK FETCH completed.
A23 FETCH 466 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 466 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A23 OK FETCH completed.
A24 FETCH 466 (BODY[TEXT]<0.427>)
* 466 FETCH (BODY[TEXT]<0> {427}
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"><!-- P {margin-top:0;margi=
n-bottom:0;} --></style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div id=3D"divtagdefaultwrapper" style=3D"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;back=
ground-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>test<br>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
 FLAGS (\Seen \Recent))
A24 OK FETCH completed.
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager watching imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
A25 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager.watch startIdle succeeded for imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 0 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imap://amith.bharathan%40drd.co.in@outlook.office365.com/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
```

The email with body "test" is repeating

Please advice.

Thanks

Amith

Comment: The log shows you read it twice (commands with tags A8 and A9)

Comment: @Outtruder I have added only one listener, But i got two emails thats my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is message number 466 in the mailbox.  The server announces the new message:

```
    * 3 RECENT
    * 466 EXISTS
```

You process the message:

```
    A16 FETCH 466 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
    ...
```

You wait for new messages, and the server tells you:

```
    * 466 EXPUNGE
    * 466 EXISTS
```

That means message number 466 was completely removed from the mailbox and there's a new message number 466 in the mailbox.  JavaMail notifies you of the new message number 466.  Apparently, it's exactly the same as the removed message number 466.

I have no idea why the server is doing that.  It looks like a bug in the server to me.  **Please report it to Microsoft.**

You might want to check the [IMAP UID](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getUID-javax.mail.Message-) of the messages that you're processing.  The new message 466 absolutely must have a different UID.  If it doesn't, that's an even more serious bug in the server.

You can also check the [Message-ID](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getMessageID--) of the message to make sure you haven't seen that message before.  If all the error cases are like this, you may only need to keep a history of one message.  But note that while Message-IDs are intended to be unique and are usually unique, unlike IMAP UIDs there's no guarantee that they **are** unique, or even that they exist at all.